# When equality holds in C-S integral inequality?

Tags: integration, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In general C-S inequality :
$(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)\geq (ax+by)^2$

We know that if $\frac{a}{x}=\frac{b}{y}$ then equality holds.

Then, when equality holds in C-S integral inequality? :
$$ (\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx)^2\leq \int_a^b f(x)^2dx\int_a^bg(x)^2dx$$

Is there any condition (in $f$ and $g$ for equality holds?

Comment: This is in all standard textbooks. Did you look? Note that the discrete case is a linear dependence condition. It's exactly the same for functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general form of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is not $(a^2 + b^2)(x^2 + y^2)\geq(ax+by)^2$—that's just another specific example of it (here, for the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the dot product as your inner product). The general inequality holds for all inner product spaces and says that $|\langle u, v\rangle|^2 \leq \langle u,u\rangle\cdot\langle v,v\rangle$, with equality precisely when $u$ and $v$ are linearly dependent, i.e. when there exists some scalar $c$ such that $u=cv$. (If you're looking for a proof of this general version, you'll find one in basically any linear algebra book, as well as on Wikipedia.) If you consider the vector space $C([a,b])$ over $\mathbb{R}$ of continuous functions on $[a,b]$, with an inner product defined by

$$\langle f, g\rangle =\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx$$

then you get the version of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality you're discussing:

$$\left( \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx\right)^2 \leq \left(\int_a^b f(x)^2 dx\right) \left(\int_a^b g(x)^2 dx\right)$$

As with the general statement of the inequality, equality holds precisely when $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent.